# "Help you" vs "help you out"

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrasal-verbs

Example:

> Actually, there's someone who can help you."
>
> Actually, there's someone who can help you out."

What's the difference between the two? Or they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 7):

[Help out / Help somebody out](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/help-out)

is to help somebody, **especially** in a difficult situation

And, simple ['help'](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/help_1?q=help) ...

is to make it easier or possible for somebody to do something by doing something for them or by giving them something that they need.

And I don't think that they are *interchangeable* in all cases though you can replace 'help out' almost always with 'help'. But the other way round may look odd.

Comment: +1 I think your "difficult situation" example is spot on. In fact, I wonder if the implication may originally have been _You are **in** a difficult situation, and someone can help you get **out** of it._

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the addition of a preposition to the verb changes the meaning, and sometimes it doesn't. People used to say that they needed to "print" a form or a report or a coupon, etc. We now hear more often "print out," which is the same thing but wordier. Offering to help is the same as offering to help out, but is again wordier.

Answer (score 1):

"To help" is the correct way; "to help out" actually comes from the German language "aushelfen-helfe aus" so maybe the phrase was written by a German